# Solving equation using list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, equation

For the past hour I've been been trying to use list comprehension to compute the solutions for the equation y = x^2 + 5. The comprehension should return the solutions as a list of ordered pairs (x,y); limit the domain of x and y as
 (both inclusive). No progress has been made so help is appreciated.

Comment: `[(x,x*x+5) for x in range(10)]`

Comment: So what have you tried, and what result did you get that wasn't what you wanted?

Comment: Try writing it in a regular for loop then convert to a comprehension.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is half an hour with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: [(x,x**2 + 5) for x in np.arange(10)]

Answer (score 0):

I would use `np.linspace` from `numpy` to accomplish this in the most efficient manner (a list comprehension is not necessary):

Preferred:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 51)

y = x**2 + 5
```

Yields:

```
[ 105.     97.16   89.64   82.44   75.56   69.     62.76   56.84   51.24
   45.96   41.     36.36   32.04   28.04   24.36   21.     17.96   15.24
   12.84   10.76    9.      7.56    6.44    5.64    5.16    5.      5.16
    5.64    6.44    7.56    9.     10.76   12.84   15.24   17.96   21.
   24.36   28.04   32.04   36.36   41.     45.96   51.24   56.84   62.76
   69.     75.56   82.44   89.64   97.16  105.  ]
```